# Project Euler Problem 7: Find 10001st prime number

Tags: project-euler, primes, f#

I was able to complete the problem, but I would like to improve my code and make it more idiomatic.

Here is the challenge description:

> Problem 7 - 10001st prime
>
> By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th >prime is 13.
>   What is the 10 001st prime number?
>
> http://projecteuler.net/problem=7

Here is my code:

```
let isDivibleBy num denum = num % denum = 0
let isPrime x previousPrimes = not (Seq.fold (fun acc y -> (isDivibleBy x y) || acc) false previousPrimes)
let getPrime n =
    let rec getPrimesInternal count num previousPrimes =
        match count with
        | 0 -> previousPrimes
        | _ -> let prime = isPrime num previousPrimes
               match prime with
               | true -> getPrimesInternal (count - 1) (num + 1) (num::previousPrimes)
               | false -> getPrimesInternal count (num + 1) previousPrimes
    match n with
    | n when n <= 0 -> 0
    | n -> List.head (getPrimesInternal (n - 1)  2 [2])


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%i" (getPrime 10001)
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

One of the major problem I would like to address is performance.  An easy way to improve the performance would be to stop the fold when a prime number is found, but I couldn't find the appropriate technique or function.

Updated version of code:

```
let isPrime n =
    match n with
    | _ when n < 2 -> false
    | 2 -> true
    | _ when n % 2 = 0 -> false // even numbers greater than 2
    | _ -> // odd numbers greater than 2
        let limit = int(sqrt(float(n)))
        let rec check i =
            i > limit || (n % i <> 0 && check (i + 2))
        check 3

let getPrimes n = 
    let rec getPrimeInternal found i = 
        if found >= n
        then []
        else 
            if isPrime i
            then i::getPrimeInternal (found + 1) (i + 1)
            else getPrimeInternal found (i + 1)
    getPrimeInternal 0 2

let getPrime n = 
    Seq.last (List.toSeq (getPrimes n))

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%i" (getPrime 10001)
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: This [question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629734/the-sieve-of-eratosthenes-in-f) is a great reference on implementing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One of the major problem I would like to address is performance.

When thinking about performance, the first question you should ask yourself is: could I use a better algorithm? Turns out there *are* better [algorithms for generating primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes), though they would be more difficult to implement (especially since they find all primes up to a certain number, which is not the same as finding the *n*-th prime).

It's probably not worth it in this case.

> An easy way to improve the performance would be to stop the fold when a prime number is found

You can use [`Seq.exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353562.aspx) for that, which will also make your code simpler:

```
let isPrime x previousPrimes = not (Seq.exists (isDivibleBy x) previousPrimes)
```

(I'm using partial function application instead of a lambda, to make the code shorter.)

---

Other notes:

```
let isDivibleBy num denum = num % denum = 0
```

I think this function should be called `isDivisibleBy`.

```
match prime with
| true -> …
| false -> …
```

This is what `if` is for.

```
 getPrimesInternal count (num + 1) previousPrimes
```

If you start with `num = 3` (and not `2`), you can be sure that all primes that you test will be odd, so you can use `num + 2` here, speeding up your code by about 50 %.

Comment: I've updated my code by your suggestion. Partial function application are great.

Answer (score 3):

Algorithmically, there are a few problems I can see.

1. Because the `previousPrimes` list is in 'reverse' order, you are checking for divisibility starting with the **least** likely divisor to the most likely divisor.  Half the integers are divisible by 2, a third divisible by 3, etc.  So an earlier exit from `Seq.exists` will happen if you iterate [2;3;5;7...]
2. You don't need to test all `previousPrimes`, only those up to the square root of `x`.
3. Most of the time is spent dealing with the `previousPrimes` list (iterating, appending, etc.).  While certainly it is correct that you only need to test prime divisors, a more naive tail-recursive `isPrime` function actually performs better:

   ```
   let isPrime =
       fun n ->
           match n with
           | _ when n < 2 -> false
           | 2 -> true
           | _ when n % 2 = 0 -> false // even numbers greater than 2
           | _ -> // odd numbers greater than 2
               let limit = int(sqrt(float(n)))
               let rec check i =
                   i > limit || (n % i <> 0 && check (i + 2))
               check 3
   ```

Getting rid of `previousPrimes` and using the above primality test function, the performance improves 3 orders of magnitude.

Comment: I've update my code by your suggestion it is indeed much faster.

Answer (score 3):

Approaching this task I'd follow "functional first" principle, then bother about performance. The solution may be as simple as:

```
let projectEuler7() = primes |> Seq.nth 10001
```

or a mere direct F# translation of [original problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=7) "Of sequence of prime numbers take 10001th member".

Now the problem is a bit simpler: effectively and lazily generate (a potentially infinite) sequence of prime numbers. Lets approach the derivative problem following the same "functional first" approach:

```
let rec primes =
    Seq.cache <| seq { yield 2; yield! Seq.unfold nextPrime 3 }
// We do cache the results for performance as we reuse already found primes
and nextPrime n = if isPrime n then Some(n, n + 2) else nextPrime(n + 2)
// obvious; our only leftover problem is effectively determine if arbitrary n is prime
and isPrime n =
    primes
    |> Seq.tryFind (fun x -> n % x = 0 || x * x > n)
    |> fun x -> x.Value * x.Value > n
// implement the obvious zero reminder condition amplified by square root limit
```

That's it! 8 lines of functional first code with not at all bad performance: on my modest laptop it delivers solution to the original problem in only 90ms. Maybe few times slower, than your final code, but way far ahead by succinctness and clarity.